# ¿Por qué mi código sobre 2 pulsadores para memorizar valores para operación AND en Arduino no funciona pero sí compila?

Tags: c, arduino

Deseo que el pulsador conmute el estado de la variables que van a operar un `AND` para que salga la función prender el led. El tiempo es para que deje de leer en el intervalo que el pulsador vuelve a abrirse. El equipo es un ARDUINO UNO.

> Leer pines de entrada. Asignar el valor a una variable para compararla en condicionales. Conmutar variable después de cumplir la condición.

[image: imagen del problema en simulador tinkercat]

```
 // C++ code
    // constantes
    const int var_PIN_BOTONPULSADOR_A = 3;
    const int var_PIN_BOTONPULSADOR_B = 7;
    const int var_PIN_SALIDA = 4;
    const int TIEMPO = 300;
    //variables
    int var_conmutar_a = 0;
    int var_conmutar_b = 0;
    int var_identidad_a = 0;
    int var_identidad_b =0;
    int var_resultado;
    
void setup()
{ 
  
  
  pinMode(var_PIN_BOTONPULSADOR_A, INPUT);
  pinMode(var_PIN_BOTONPULSADOR_B, INPUT);
  pinMode(var_PIN_SALIDA, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() 
  
{  
  var_conmutar_a  = digitalRead(var_PIN_BOTONPULSADOR_A);
  var_conmutar_b  = digitalRead(var_PIN_BOTONPULSADOR_B);
  if  (var_conmutar_a == HIGH){
     var_identidad_a = !var_identidad_a;
    delay(TIEMPO);
  }
  if  (var_conmutar_b == HIGH){
     var_identidad_b = !var_identidad_b;
    delay(TIEMPO);
  }
  if(var_identidad_a && var_identidad_b == HIGH){
  var_resultado = HIGH;
    delay(TIEMPO);
  }
  if(var_identidad_a && var_identidad_b == LOW){
  var_resultado = LOW;
  delay(TIEMPO);
  }
  ;
     
   digitalWrite(var_PIN_SALIDA, var_resultado );
  // var_resultado = (var_identidad_a && var_identidad_b)
  
  /*if (digitalRead(entrada_a) != entrada_a)
 if ((digitalRead(3)) ||(digitalRead(7)) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);} */
 

 
}
```

Comment: 1. ¡NO ES NECESARIO GRITAR! 2. Dale el formato correspondiente al código y describe el problema en cuestión (no coloques solo código). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Compila pues el código cumple con la sintaxis. Que compile no significa que vaya a producir el resultado deseado.

Comment: Todos esos `delay()` no sirven para nada. El problema con el código que no haces "debouncing" de los pulsadores.

Comment: `var_identidad_a && var_identidad_b == HIGH` realiza una conversión implícita de `var_identidad_a` a bool. No se "encadenan" las comparaciones. La manera correcta sería `var_identidad_a == HIGH && var_identidad_b == HIGH`

Comment: Revisa está solución https://www.instructables.com/The-AND-Gate-With-Arduino/. Puedes encontrar otras buscando "Arduino and logic gate"

Answer (score 3):

#### Uso de pulsadores

Existen varias formas de conectar pulsadores a Arduino. Mi preferida es conectar el pin Arduino a un lado del pulsador y el otro a GND:

[image: Conexión Arduino Pulsador]

En lugar de usar una resistencia externa de pullup, usamos la resistencia de pullup interna de Arduino, abriendo el pin con opción `INPUT_PULLUP`:

```
pinMode(var_PIN_BOTONPULSADOR_A, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

Esta modalidad se llama *Active Low*, que significa que cuando el pulsador está activo (presionado), el pin lee una señal LOW. Obvio, existe *Active High*, donde el pulsador conecta con VCC y el pin lee HIGH al estar presionado.

Con Active Low puedo usar INPUT_PULLUP y simplificar el circuito al eliminar la resistencia externa.

En este configuración, cuando presiones el pulsador con

```
var_conmutar_a  = digitalRead(var_PIN_BOTONPULSADOR_A);
```

leeras un LOW solo mientras esté presionado (un HIGH en otro caso). Por tanto, se requiere invertir los condicionales.

#### Debouncing

El problema con los pulsadores es que no producen una señal limpia. Durante unos milisegundos, el circuito se abre y se cierra unas cuantas veces, antes de que la conexión se estabilice.

[image: Activación de un pulsador]

La conclusión es que una sola lectura del pulsador no basta (en general); tienes que repetir las lecturas hasta detectar que la entrada es estable.

Hay soluciones de hardware y software para este problema, pero en tu caso particular no realmente necesario y podemos obviarlo.

#### Solución

Nota: tienes que recablear los pulsadores: un cable del pin al pulsador, y del otro lado, una conexión a GND.

Esta solución conmutara el LED cada vez que presiones ambos pulsadores. El LED continuara encendido hasta repetir la operación.

El `setup()` solo cambia el modo de apertura:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(var_PIN_BOTONPULSADOR_A, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(var_PIN_BOTONPULSADOR_B, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(var_PIN_SALIDA, OUTPUT);
}
```

En el `loop()` queremos detectar cuando ambas señales estén en LOW al mismo tiempo y en tal caso, conmutar el LED.

El problema es que la condición se va a dar mientras no se suelten los botones, y el LED va a parpadear.

Para evitar eso, agregamos el booleano `button_on`. Este será `1` al detectar ambos pulsadores presionados, y se mantendrá así hasta que ambos se suelten.

```
void loop() {
  static bool button_on = 0;
  
  var_conmutar_a  = digitalRead(var_PIN_BOTONPULSADOR_A);
  var_conmutar_b  = digitalRead(var_PIN_BOTONPULSADOR_B);

  if  (var_conmutar_a == LOW and var_conmutar_b == LOW and button_on == 0) {
    button_on = 1;
    var_resultado = !var_resultado;
    digitalWrite(var_PIN_SALIDA, var_resultado );
    }
   else if (var_conmutar_a == HIGH and var_conmutar_b == HIGH) {
    button_on = 0;
   }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para conmutar el estado de una variable con un pulsador en Arduino, puedes usar un circuito conectado al pin de entrada del Arduino y a una resistencia pull-down. Cuando el pulsador se presiona, la señal en el pin de entrada del Arduino se vuelve alta y cuando el pulsador se suelta, la señal vuelve a ser baja.

Puedes usar una estructura de control de flujo if para verificar el estado del pulsador y cambiar el estado de la variable que operará el AND. Por ejemplo:

```
const int buttonPin = 2;    // pin del pulsador
const int ledPin = 13;      // pin del LED
bool ledState = false;      // estado inicial del LED (apagado)

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);    // configura el pin del pulsador con una resistencia pull-up
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);             // configura el pin del LED como salida
}

void loop() {
  // lee el estado del pulsador
  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // si el pulsador está presionado (valor LOW)
  if (buttonState == LOW) {
    // cambia el estado del LED
    ledState = !ledState;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);

    // espera a que el pulsador se suelte
    while (digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW) {
      delay(10);
    }
  }
}
```

Este código lee el estado del pulsador en cada iteración del bucle loop() y, si el pulsador está presionado, cambia el estado del LED y espera a que el pulsador se suelte antes de continuar.

Es importante usar una resistencia pull-up o pull-down en el circuito del pulsador para evitar un estado indeterminado cuando el pulsador no está siendo presionado.

Comment: El OP usa dos pulsadores que deben conmutar un LED cuando ambos están pulsados. ¿Lo copiaste sin más de chatGPT? Eso está prohibido en este sitio.

Comment: Por otra parte, quedarse pegado dentro de `loop()` esperando algo es pésima práctica. Cada pasada por `loop()` debe ser tan corta como sea posible. Revisa el ejemplo estándar "BlinkWithoutDelay".